# How Can I Save Selected Form Option in Vue to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I have a collection that I want  the option selected by the user submitted to in firebase.

```
<select v-model="selected">
<option disabled value="">Marital Status</option>
<option>Married</option>
<option>Single</option>
<option>Divorced</option>
<option>Widow</option>
</select>
```

When I bind the form select  with profile.maritalStatus, the option selected will be submitted to profile collection in firebase, but the placeholder on the select form won't show on the page.
How can I bind with v-model="selected" and be able to submit it to the profile collection.

```
data (){
selected:"",
profile:{
maritalStatus: null,
age: null, 
profession: null,
}
},

methods:{
Save(){   db.collection("profile").add(this.profile)
}
}
```

I want a placeholder like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: ''
  },
  watch:{
   selected:function(){
     console.log('selected is ' +this.selected+" do you logic here");
   }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="app">
<select v-model="selected">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Marital Status</option>
    <option>Married</option>
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Divorced</option>
    <option>Widow</option>
</select>
Selected:{{selected}}
</div>
</body>
```

Are you looking for something like this?

```
    <select name="maritalStatus" v-model="selected">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Marital Status</option>
        <option>Married</option>
        <option>Single</option>
        <option>Divorced</option>
        <option>Widow</option>
    </select>
```

Additionally you can add a watcher to call save()

```
watch:{
  selected:function(new,old){
   //write your logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: I want the placeholder to still be present on the form and still be able to submit to profile collection, binding to profile will submit to profile collection but the placeholder won't appear, it is important and I want it there. Any suggestion please!